# Bus error with mmap memory region

Tags: c++, mmap

In the following simple program:

```
# include <sys/mman.h>
# include <fcntl.h>
# include <cstdlib>

# include <cassert>

struct rgn_desc
{
  size_t end_;
  char data[];
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
  int fd = open("foo.mm", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, (mode_t)0700);

  assert(fd != -1);

  void * ptr = mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                    MAP_SHARED | MAP_POPULATE, fd, 0);

  assert(ptr != (void*) -1);

  rgn_desc * rgn_ptr = (rgn_desc*) ptr;
  rgn_ptr->end_ = 0; // <-- bus error
}
```

Basically, I want to manage a simple mmaped arena allocator and store as first part of the mapping the bytes that I have allocated. So, when I recover from a file, I get how many bytes were allocated.

However, the last line is giving me a `bus error`. Could someone explain why, and if possible, to suggest to me a way for avoiding it. I am running Linux on a 32 bits pentium and using clang++ compiler

Comment: Replace the `assert` statement with `if (ptr == MAP_FAILED) perror("mmap"), exit(EXIT_FAILURE);` then use the debugger and `strace`

Comment: I put @Basile suggestion (`if (ptr == MAP_FAILED...`) and removed MAP_POPULATE. I get still the error.

Comment: Did you also use `strace`?

Comment: @Stargateur: that should be the answer.

Comment: That works with `ftruncate(fd, 4096);`.Please publish the answer and I will be glad to upvote and accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the doc, a sig bus can trigger if:

> ```
> SIGBUS
>     Attempted access to a portion of the buffer that does not
>     correspond to the file (for example, beyond the end of the
>     file, including the case where another process has truncated
>     the file).
> ```

In your snipped your file size don't match with your [`mmap()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) size (0, 4096), so you could use [`ftruncate()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/truncate.2.html) to increase the size of your file.

```
ftruncate(fd, 4096);
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Only a thing: I wouldn't be sure that your citation about `MAP_POPULATE` excludes it of using for non-private mappings. What I understand is that the support is since 2.6.23 not before, but that does not imply, as I interpret it, that used in conjunction with other flags is forbidden.